# VB6 msbuild compile attempts to load log4net

Tags: msbuild, vb6, log4net

I am attempting to create a build / development environment for our application developers and automated build machine on Windows 10x86. As part of this process I have installed VB6 and can successfully load our code base. When I compile I successfully get our application.exe file. However, after the file has been compile, the build process reports the following

> Attempting to load log4net from the app config file...
>   log4net : error XmlConfigurator: Failed to parse config file. Is the 
>    specified as:  [C:\Build\AmazingCharts\Working\Building\Build\CompileVB6.msbuild]
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred
>   creating the configuration section handler for l   og4net: Could not
>   load file or assembly 'log4net' or one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specifi   ed. (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\VB98\VB6.EXE.config line 4) --->
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could    not load file or assembly
>   'log4net' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.
>        at System.Configuration.TypeUtil.GetTypeWithReflectionPermission(IInternalConfigHost
>   host, String typeString, Bool   ean throwOnError)
>        at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.Init(RuntimeConfigurationRecord
>   con   figRecord, FactoryRecord factoryRecord) ...

This error is trimmed for brevity.

Things I have confirmed.

- log4net.dll exists in the working directory
- I have tried using the *MSBuild.ExtensionPack.VisualStudio.VB6* task and the *EXEC* task to compile our VB6 project file.
- This msbuild code works correctly on our current Windows 7x86 machine.
- I am compiling with UAC turned off
- I have verified that the vb6.exe file compatibility properties have been set  to Windows XP (Service Pack 3) mode for all users.
- I also set the options so that the EXE is run as administrator for all users.
- We have to have a .config file for VB6.EXE in order for it to interact with .NET Framework 4

  - config file used to only have the `<startup ... >` element defined to handle the supportedRuntime version="v4.0" attribute.
- I have added a `<configSections ... >` since getting the above errors.
- I have created a log4net element, a root child element where the level is set to OFF, which if I understand correctly should disable logging.

  But the problem seems to be in the attempt to load log4net ... which I do not understand why msbuild is attempting to load for this project type.

Below is the error message without any log4net info added to the config file:

> Attempting to load log4net from the the app config file.. log4net :
>   error XmlConfigurator: Failed to find configuration section 'log4net'
>   in the application's .config file. Chec k your .config file for the
>   `<log4net>` and `<configSections>` elements. The configuration section
>   should look like: `<section name="log4net"
>   type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />`
>   [C:\Build\AmazingCharts\Working\Building\Build\CompileVB6.msbuild]
>   C:\Build\AmazingCharts\Working\Building\Build\CompileVB6.msbuild(22,3):
>   error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files\M icrosoft Visual
>   Studio\VB98\VB6.EXE" /m
>   "C:\Build\AmazingCharts\Working\Building\vb6\charts.vbp"" exited with
>   code -1. Done Building Project
>   "C:\Build\AmazingCharts\Working\Building\Build\CompileVB6.msbuild"
>   (default targets) -- FAILED.

Any ideas on how to resolve this problem or even allow msbuild to ignore the error and continue for now?

---

**EDIT:**
This must be a product of the msbuild system. If I create a simple batch file and execute the same EXEC command then the process works and there isn't any prompt for log4net.

Comment: Is it possible that another version of log4net is being used by msbuild?

Comment: You can probably avoid all this by [loading the log4net config from a standalone file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24845646/43846) which gets it out of the app.config. It's a minimal change where you load the log4net configuration to specify a file (make sure it's copied to the output)

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Is there a way to identify the version of log4net.dll being loaded by msbuild?